# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.4 incredibly slow

Tags: 16.04, gnome, system-installation

I have a HP Probook 4530s, i5 processor with 16GB of RAM, that I used with Win10 and with OSX El Capitan (hackintosh) for quite a while, both working really well.

I had a couple of free hard disk, so I decided to put one inside and install Kubuntu 16.04.4, and the other with Ultimate Edition 5.7, to try different flavours.
Well, both are running amazingly slow, to a point where I can't use my computer.
So I formatted and installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 Gnome as a more standard release and... this is even worse!
To be clear, when I change OS i litterally change the disk inside, so no dualboot or other stuff, just a clean install and a single HD inside.

I can't understand why, the computer is not exactly new, I understand, but it's still an i5 with 16 GB of ram, Win10 and OSX are litteraly flying on it.
I ran any possible test (Ram, HD) but everything seems to be fine in HW.

Any advice please? It seems really strange to me that Ubuntu is so amazingly demanding in resources.
Note that my notebook has a double GPU, but I disabled the switching in bios (as it is handled by windows driver), so I always run it with the standard intel 3000 gpu on all the OS's (win10, osx and ubuntu).

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your GPU is not recognized as such. Did you run Drivers manager to make sure that it does not need more drivers installed?

Comment: Thank you, but it's hard even to reach the Drivers manager! Actually it's really unusable.

Comment: Thank you, I checked but the GPU is recognized. Btw resolution is ok in laptop and (if I connect) external monitor. Oddly enough, if I leave it there for a while it become more usable, but with a lot of trouble, i.e. software center appears empty.

Answer (score 0):

The driver are ok, oddly enough it become a little better (almost usable, not really) after a while if I leave it alone.

There are other strange things, i.e. the software center open but it's completly empty, a white page, although the internet connection is fine (checked with firefox, pages open correctly)

I supposed a wide distribution like Ubuntu, on a standard machine like an HP Probook, must be a breeze to install, but I had quite a delusion.
Is it possible that (ok, I'm ignorant, this might be a stupid question) having 16 Gb of RAM the swap partition is not dimensioned correctly?

In my mind, being Ubuntu around 2 Gb, the swap file shouldn't even be touched, nevertheless...